# How to loop asking for a file name, while still including FileNotFoundException message?

Tags: java, file

I'm working on part of a Java program that is trying to read a file in the project folder. I'm also throwing a "file not found" message if the user inputs a file name that does not exist. However, I'm struggling trying to come up with a loop that repeats until the user inputs a valid file name. Here's what I'm working with:

```
public class MyUtils {
    public static void readFile(String read) {
        File f = new File(read);
        try {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);
            while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
                String info = sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println(info);
            }
            sc.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found. Try again: ");
        }       
    }
}
```

**EDIT** I forgot to include where this method is called. My apologies! See here:

```
System.out.print("Input file name: ");
String filetxt = sc.nextLine();
filetxt = filetxt.toLowerCase();
MyUtils.readFile(filetxt);
```

Comment: How the user input the file name? I can see, you pass the file name to this method from wherever user entered it. If you need a loop to ask the user to try again, that loop should be there.

Comment: Please add the code where you get the user input file name as well.

Comment: @SachithDickwella my apologies! Just fixed it.

Comment: Besides @ariefbayu's answer, why do you need to capture the exception inside the function? And then, why cannot you re-throw the exception so the outside caller can catch and retry? If both have a concrete reason, then you could go to arieftbayu's solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would convert return value of `readFile()` to `Boolean` and have a boolean variable assignment based on success of false of your code and then, return the boolean variable.

```
public static Boolean readFile(String read) {
    Boolean isSuccess = false;
    File f = new File(read);
    try {
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);
      while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String info = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println(info);
      }
      sc.close();
      isSuccess = true;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      System.out.println("File not found. Try again: ");
      isSuccess = false;
    }
    return isSuccess;
}
```

Next, you would just check if `readFile()` is false and ask user another file.

```
while(!MyUtils.readFile(filename)){
    filename = askAnotherFile();
}
```